# Evaluate $\int_1^\infty \frac {43\ln(x)}{x} dx $ if it exists

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

***Question:*** Evaluate if exists
$$\int_1^\infty \frac {43\ln(x)}{x} dx $$

***My answer***:
By using integration by substitution, 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac {43\ln(x)}{x} dx =[43(\ln(x))^2]_1^\infty=\infty-0=\infty$$
So this integral does not exist. 
Does this seem correct? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is down-voted.  Why is it illegitimate for the OP to ask if he's done the problem correctly?  Is it because the title isn't specific enough?  Fair enough, but why not leave a comment so the OP will know better next time?

Comment: @saulspatz there are some people in the community whose sole job is to downvote question and they feel very happy and contended after doing so.

Comment: @saulspatz this is a fair point. OP also clearly did work!

Comment: I edited the title to make it more specific, please let me know if this is ok

Comment: You made a couple of mistakes.  First, when you make the substitution $u=\ln x,$ you also need to change the limits of integration.  As $x$ goes from $1$ to $\infty, \ln x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ so the lower limit of integration on the second integral must be $0$.  This isn't too much trouble in this case, because if the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ doesn't exist, neither does the integral from $0$ to $\infty.$  The other small error is that you forgot the factor of $1/2$ when you integrated.

Comment: How could it possibly converge? The integrand is above $43/x$ for $x\ge e$ and that gives a diverging minorant. It would not occur to me to actually look for a primitive (not that it is difficult here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your result is correct (modulo some constant issues in the antiderivative and the bounds). Note that without computing, we can see that for $x>e$, $\ln x>1$. So 
$$
\int_{e}^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x}\mathrm dx\geq \int_{e}^\infty \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: Lower limit of integration is incorrect also.

Comment: @saulspatz you are right, I didn't see